# What do I initialise each model in cross validation with in a multi-layer Perceptron?

Tags: neural-network, cross-validation, training, mnist

So, as far as my understanding goes, cross-validation is used to determine the best model.

I understand that once we determine the best model, we then train it on the entire dataset. I'm supposed to be using cross-validation for the multi-layer perceptron that can classify the MNIST dataset. I don't seem to get how cross-validation fits in training the model.

Let's say I'm using 5-fold cross-validation, which means I will have to make 5 different models but, how will the training of these individual model proceed? In particular, I have the following questions:

1. Will the training of these individual model be as usual(backward propagation)?
2. What do I initialise each model with? (Random Weights?)
3. After completing the cross-validation, I have the best model(say B) with me now, what does it mean to train this model on the entire dataset? 
   (Does it mean, I initialise the weights of the new model being trained on the whole dataset, with those of B).

Comment: You are not searching for the common cross validation, but for the hyperparameter tuning cross validation. In fact,  this CV is not used to find the **best model**, but is used to find the **best parameter** for the model!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do **cross validation with hyperparameter tuning**, so here is how it's done with k-fold CV (from this [answer](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-combine-k-fold-cross-validation-with-hyperparameter-tuning)):

You can split your data into 2 datasets: training and test. *k-folds cross validation* takes a model (and specified hyperparameters) and partitions the training dataset into *k* equally sized subsets. Then, it does the following *k* times:

- Trains the model on *k-1* of the subsets
- Evaluates the model accuracy on the subset that wasn’t trained on.

It then reports the average error. To do **hyperparameter tuning**, do the steps above using every time a different hyperparameter combinations. Then, choose the set of parameters for which k-folds reports the lowest error. However, be careful to not excessively minimize the k-folds error, since it will often lead to overfitting.

Ultimately, we want a measure of how well our final model will generalize. This is why we created the test set at the beginning—evaluating the model’s accuracy on this set is a useful estimation of its success.

So, *k-fold* doesn't mean *k* different models, but *k* folds of the dataset!

To reply to your questions:

> Will the training of these individual model be as usual(backward propagation)?

Yes each training is *as usual*, just changes the training set and the hyperparameters.

> What do I initialise each model with? (Random Weights?)

Yes, (still) *as usual* in neural networks. You are not re-using old weights.

> After completing the cross-validation, I have the best model(say B) with me now, what does it mean to train this model on the entire dataset? (Does it mean, I initialise the weights of the new model being trained on the whole dataset, with those of B).

Well, you are mistakenly exchanging again weights and hyperparameters, but, if you have a very big dataset and cross validating on the entire dataset takes too long, you can:

- take a portion of your dataset (maybe 10%), let's call it A
- Use A to find the *best hyperparameters* using k-fold CV as I described before
- Now you can use the entire dataset for training (except a test set) the model using those *best hyperparameters*. With the hope that's the *real* best model.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just have one clarification to make: You say while answering my last question that, "mistakenly exchanging again weights and hyperparameters",  so that means,  hyperparameters are something like batch size, learning rate, etc..., but not the weights learned?

Comment: exactly! Because weights depend on the data you use for training, while hyperparameters are those parameters that only the 'creator' of the model can decide!